# Invoke-WebRequest POST InFile from remote network chain of events

Tags: powershell, file-io, invoke-webrequest

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Method "POST" -Uri $uri -InFile $fileToAttach
```

In the above web request:

- $uri points to a public website.
- $fileToAttach points to a remote file share (Access via VPN).
- My connection is public internet (home internet), connected to above VPN to access the file share.

When I run this command, does the $fileToAttach download to my PC (in memory?) and then the file is sent to $uri? If not, what is the chain of events that happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test with Wireshark showed that `Invoke-WebRequest`, in order:

1. Starts a TCP connection to the destination server `$uri`
2. Loads the entire `-InFile` file from the remote server into memory,
3. Continues with the connection in 1, processing https/auth steps,
4. Posts the file

Comment: Thank you - I really need to get acquainted with Wireshark.